# Css Issue with rating

Tags: html, css

**Issue**

1. Value is overlapping with my star rating.
2. Also i want line break only after 2 options like

> ```
> Value *****  Ambience *****
> service***** Food *****
> ```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sheldoncopper/j3dsy29L/)

**css**

```
 .rating {
 width: 95px;
 height: 19px;
 background: url(http://njerd.com/images/misc/StarRating.png) -113px 0 no-repeat;
 }

 .rating_05 {background-position: -95px 0;}
 .rating_10 {background-position: -76px -23px;}
 .rating_15 {background-position: -76px 0;}
 .rating_20 {background-position: -57px -23px;}
 .rating_25 {background-position: -57px 0;}
 .rating_30 {background-position: -38px -23px;}
 .rating_35 {background-position: -38px 0;}
 .rating_40 {background-position: -19px -23px;}
 .rating_45 {background-position: -19px 0;}
 .rating_50 {background-position: 0 0;}
```

**html**

```
<div class="rating rating_40"> Value</div>
<div class="rating rating_40"> Ambiance</div>
<div class="rating rating_45"> Service</div>
<div class="rating rating_45"> Food</div>
<div class="rating rating_25"> Music</div>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you check my answer? It should be the easiest, most robust solution to the problem and does not require additional html elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `display: table`

```css
.rating {
   display: table;    
}
.rating-row{
    display: table-row;
}
.rating-text,
.ratiog-star{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.rating-star{       
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(http://njerd.com/images/misc/StarRating.png) -113px 0 no-repeat;
    width: 95px;
    height: 19px;  
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.rating_05 {background-position: -95px 0;}
.rating_10 {background-position: -76px -23px;}
.rating_15 {background-position: -76px 0;}
.rating_20 {background-position: -57px -23px;}
.rating_25 {background-position: -57px 0;}
.rating_30 {background-position: -38px -23px;}
.rating_35 {background-position: -38px 0;}
.rating_40 {background-position: -19px -23px;}
.rating_45 {background-position: -19px 0;}
.rating_50 {background-position: 0 0;}
```

```html
<div class="rating"> 
    <div class="rating-row">
        <div class="rating-text">Value</div>
        <div class="rating-star rating_40"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="rating-row"> 
        <div class="rating-text">Ambiance</div>
        <div class="rating-star rating_40"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="rating-row">
        <div class="rating-text">Service</div>
        <div class="rating-star rating_45"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="rating-row"> 
        <div class="rating-text">Value</div>
        <div class="rating-star rating_40"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-row">
        <div class="rating-text">Food</div>
        <div class="rating-star rating_45"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-row">
        <div class="rating-text">Music</div>
        <div class="rating-star rating_25"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

use `:after`

```css
.rating {
  
}
.rating:after{    
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(http://njerd.com/images/misc/StarRating.png) -113px 0 no-repeat;
    width: 95px;
    height: 19px;  
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.rating_05:after {background-position: -95px 0;}
.rating_10:after {background-position: -76px -23px;}
.rating_15:after {background-position: -76px 0;}
.rating_20:after {background-position: -57px -23px;}
.rating_25:after {background-position: -57px 0;}
.rating_30:after {background-position: -38px -23px;}
.rating_35:after {background-position: -38px 0;}
.rating_40:after {background-position: -19px -23px;}
.rating_45:after {background-position: -19px 0;}
.rating_50:after {background-position: 0 0;}
```

```html
<div class="rating rating_40"> Value</div>
<div class="rating rating_40"> Ambiance</div>
<div class="rating rating_45"> Service</div>
<div class="rating rating_45"> Food</div>
<div class="rating rating_25"> Music</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the stars in/on a `span` inside the `div`, and have 2 "items" in each div.

Fixed [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3dsy29L/1/)

Comment: You could utilize tables or css display attribute to table types (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: Not necessary, see my answer below. It can be easily done without changing html.

Comment: @connexo your solution requires higher standard support (CSS3) and therefore won't work with some browsers. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Comment: That is true for the :nth-of-type pseudo selector, yes. But of course this can also be solved by adding a css class on every third item. I've added this below. Still NO additional markup required.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a markup change here. Check the updated fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/j3dsy29L/3/

Just add some style rules:

```
.rating {
    float: left;
    width: 95px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(http://njerd.com/images/misc/StarRating.png) -113px 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -70px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.rating:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

If you need to support old browsers that do not understand `:nth-of-type()` pseudo selector, this can also be solved by adding a css class on every third item: 
`.rating.new-line { clear: left; }`

```
<div class="rating rating_40"> Value</div> 
<div class="rating rating_40"> Ambiance</div> 
<div class="rating rating_45 new-line"> Service</div> 
<div class="rating rating_45"> Food</div> 
<div class="rating rating_25"> Music</div>
```